# How can I lazily evaluate read-line to gather input?

Tags: clojure

(The following was originally a homework assignment, but I'm trying it in a new language.)

In a short Clojure program, I attempt to generate a lazy sequence of inputs (from the command line) and from them calculate three character values. I would assume that, possibly depending on how Clojure chose to evaluate my `let` bindings, this ought to produce a prompt series like the following:

```
$ clj lazy-prompts.clj
Enter value #1: 32
Enter value #3: 162
Enter value #2: 12
Enter value #4: 118
a A 5
```

Instead, the program begins and hangs infinitely with no prompts. I tried eagerly evaluating the `for` expression by wrapping it in `dorun`, but that did not change the outcome.

**Why does the following program produce no input prompts?**

```
(use '[clojure.java.io :only (reader)])

(def of-input
    (for [value-number [1 2 3 4]]
        (dorun
            (print (str "Enter encrypted value #" value-number))
            (read-line)
        )))

(let [value-1 (nth of-input 1)
      value-2 (nth of-input 2)
      value-3 (nth of-input 3)
      value-4 (nth of-input 4)]

    (let [a (/ (+ value-1 value-3) 2)
          b (/ (+ value-2 value-4) 2)
          c (- value-4 b)]

        (println (char a) (char b) (char c))))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should replace dorun with do. The former expects a seq as its first or second argument and forces it.

After that change, the code more or less runs correctly. What you observe as "hanging" is actually waiting for your input. One of the problems is, that you don't see the prompts (yet). They actually show, but only after you enter four values. How do you fix that? I don't know, I always thought that having side effects in a lazy sequence is a bad idea, so I never do that.

The other problem is, that read-line returns strings and you're using them as numbers. You'll have to convert them first.

P.S. "for" in clojure is not a for-loop, it is a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

`print` does not flush the output, so you don't see the prompts immediately. Either use `println` or call `flush` explicitly, like so:

```
(def of-input
(for [value-number [1 2 3 4]]
    (dorun
        (print (str "Enter encrypted value #" value-number))
        (flush)
        (read-line)
    )))
```